# putting a pdf online within a viewer that has flip/page turn effect and works on iPad

Tags: web-services, web-applications, pdf

I was wanting to do something like this for a PDF

http://www.ixian.co.nz/mainzeal/mainsite/Dec2010.html

But that service appears to be a paid for solution. I was wondering if there is anything out there open source that can do the same thing? I.e I give it a PDF and it can turn it into a browsable book, like the above, complete with page flip effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, didn't find much aside from scribd.com which is obviously not the same thing.

Comment: Did you look at Dan's solution below?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at FlexPaper Zine

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/flexpaper_flip_zine.jsp